# Spring-ldap via annotations instead of XML

Tags: annotations, spring-boot, spring-ldap

I have got the answers for setting up LdapContextSource and LdapTemplate without XML configurations from the SO question [Best practice for configuring Spring LdapTemplate via annotations instead of XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515345/best-practice-for-configuring-spring-ldaptemplate-via-annotations-instead-of-xml)

What should be the annotation way for the below xml - automatically creating repository beans based on interfaces?

```
<ldap:repositories base-package="org.springframework.ldap.samples.useradmin.domain" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableLdapRepositories("org.springframework.ldap.samples.useradmin.domain")
public class LdapConfiguration { ... }
```

The [`@EnableLdapRepositories`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/repository/config/EnableLdapRepositories.java) takes care of adding the correct configuration and scanning for repositories.

Comment: And dependency `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>` should be added to use CrudRepository

Comment: No it shouldn't... That is for JPA not for LDAP... You should just add the `spring-data-commons` dependency.