# How to use Autowired annotations

Tags: spring

I have a doubt to use autowire annotation in different scenarios...

```
public Class A {
  @Autowired
  public B b;

  public void print() {
    System.out.println("the value is " + b.getValue());
  }

}
```

Example 2:

```
public Class A {
  public B b;

  @Autowired
  Public A(B b){}

  public void print() {
    System.out.println("the value is " + b.getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks in advance.. what is the dfifference in these two use cases..

Comment: What's your question? The first one uses field injection. The second one uses constructor injection. Read the documentation. Also, none of your code is valid Java code, and is indented. Take some care before pressing the submit button.

Comment: http://coders-kitchen.com/2015/01/05/dependency-injection-field-vs-constructor-vs-method/ read this.

Comment: Thankyou JB Nizet.. can you refer some documents for detailed explanation on this

Answer (score 0):

The first method to *autowire* objects is called *field-injection* and the second one is called *constructor-injection*. There are many posts on SO about these two topics! E.g. [What exactly is Field Injection and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it)
This should answer all of your questions.