# java.lang.NullPointerException calling Datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have library module which I want to use to store Hibernate models. I ask have Spring WAR package which I want to use.

Main Spring WAR:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextDatasource {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws NamingException {
        final LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.plugin.database.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
        return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/global/production_gateway");
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() throws NamingException {
        final HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
        final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

Library DAO:

```
public class BlacklistsDaoHibernate implements BlacklistsDao {

    Session session;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public BlacklistsDaoHibernate() {
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(BlacklistsModel blacklistsModel) throws Exception {
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            session.saveOrUpdate(blacklistsModel);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            throw new Exception("Error");
        }
    }
```

But I get NPE at this line `session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`

What is the proper way to use sessionFactory into the Library Jar module?

Comment: Relevant: [What exactly is Field Injection and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Comment: How is `sessionFactory` supposed to be set before the constructor completes, meaning before an instance of `BlacklistsDaoHibernate` even exists to be operated on?

Comment: @luk2302 should I use @Postconstruct?

Comment: No, you should use constructor injection.

Comment: @luk2302 can you please post example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @PostConstruct or constructor injection. Spring instantiates your object, *then* resolves its @Autowired fields. You can ask that it resolve your object's dependencies prior to instantiating the object via constructor injection.

With constructor injection:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;
public BlacklistsDaoHibernate(@Autowired SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    this.session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

With @PostConstruct:

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session;

@PostConstruct
void init() {
    this.session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

**Edit:** If your goal is just to resolve the NullPointerException as mentioned in the comments, use this instead:

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

There's an example of the typical usage of `SessionFactory` at https://www.java2novice.com/hibernate/session-factory.

Comment: I get null for session.

Comment: Are you starting the session on SessionFactory somewhere else? The point of calling `.getCurrentSession()` is so you don't create a bunch of extra sessions throughout your program. Usually this is handled by creating a custom "session factory" that injects `SessionFactory` and when some kind of getSession() function is called, checks to see if a session has already been opened. If not, it begins a new session and returns that.

Comment: No, I suppose that my SessionFactory is not correct. Can you check it am I missing something?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Take a look at my edit to this answer. Does that help?

Comment: I suspect that I'm not properly configuring the application startup. Can you please take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242707/nosuchmethodexception-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-http-httpmessageco

Comment: Nah. I've already answered your question and you downvoted me in response, so I'm not interested in solving your other problems.

Comment: It's not my down vote.

Comment: Should I use @Transactional in order to activate @Autowired?