# Dependency injection on a protected field using @Inject

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

If I had an abstract class that was inherited by many other classes, would `@Inject` be alright on a protected object to use it in the children classes ?

Here is a shortened example:

Abstract class inherited from:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
//Many imports
public abstract class FatherMessageHandler{

    //All the neeeded code...
    @Inject
    protected MyMessageHandler messageHandler;
}
```

One of the child class:

```
public class UseMessageHandler extends FatherMessageHandler {

        //All the neeeded code...
          MyMessageHandler.getMessageAlert();
}
```

Is it good practice to do so ? Is it a no go ? Or is there a cleaner way ? I'm asking this as I'm quite new to injections !

Comment: DI is better on constructors as it eases unit tests.

Comment: Field injection is obsolete and discouraged, i.e. you should probably use it only for legacy code where it's too expensive to change injection approach. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892204/4494577) for details.

Comment: @jannis Indeed, this is a rather old code on a huge project which i'm working on as a junior, so there's not much we can change in the "injection approach" at this point. Thanks for the link, i'll make sure to read the thread !