# How to fix "Application failed to start" in spring boot and it asks for a bean to be defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, dependency-injection

My Spring boot app runs but says failed to start and it says the following:

> Field userDetailsService in com.example.security.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.example.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:

- `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl' in your configuration.

I have tried adding `@Bean` and `@Service` annotations in my UserDetailsServiceImpl class and adding the beanutils dependency in the pom.xml file but it still issues the same message of failing to start.

My `UserDetailsServiceImpl` class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

import com.example.domain.User;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;

public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with username: " + username + " not found");

        }
        return new CustomSpringUser (user); 
    }
}
```

It should say something like successfully ran Spring-Boot app.

Comment: Show where this bean is supposed to be autowired

Comment: I am not too sure about that. If I have to guess, I have to say UserRepository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BeanUtils won't help you in this case. The `UserDetailsService` cannot be properly injected since it is not registered as a bean, which only the following annotations are suitable to do so:

- `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller` or `@Component` where I highly recommend `@Service` in this case.

The annotation **must** be placed on the **class level** since you want to inject its instance. Of course, the class must be an implementation of the interface that is the implementation injected in.

```
@Service // must be on the class level
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // method implementation...
    }
}
```

On top of that, I recommend you to read the following links:

- About dependency injection is Spring at [Baeldung's website](https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring).
- About component scanning and component types at [JavaCodeGeeks](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/11/difference-component-service-controller-repository-spring.html) and [What's the difference between @Component, @Repository & @Service annotations in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827752/whats-the-difference-between-component-repository-service-annotations-in)
- About advantages of the constructor injection over the field one at [Field Dependency Injection Considered Harmful](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/) and [What exactly is Field Injection and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Comment: Glad it works, you are welcome :) Please, don't forget to read those articles to get well with Spring.

Answer (score 3):

Put @Service annotation on your UserDetailsServiceImpl class.