# Should I manually reset state-data of Autowired Bean in Spring (since it is Singleton)?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jmstemplate

I am using **org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;** in my project to send messages to SQS queues.

I autowired JmsTemplate in a @Service

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AmazonSQSPublisherImpl implements AmazonSQSPublisher {
    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    @Override
    public boolean sendMessageToFifo(String queueName, String message,
                                     String messageGroupId, String messageDedupeId, long delayTime) throws EventBrokerException {
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryDelay(delayTime);
        jmsTemplate.send(queueName, session -> {/* somemessage here*/});
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String queueName, String message) throws EventBrokerException {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, message);
    }
}
```

Here I use **setDeliveryDelay** inside the jmsTemplate. So my question is: 
As I known, bean is singleton by default. if I used the setter of the jmsTemplate bean, should I reset it? In my example, should I add this at the end of method sendMessageToFifo:

```
jmsTemplate.setDeliveryDelay(0);
```

If I don't add this, when I call **sendMessage** rather than **sendMessageToFifo**, the delivery delay will not be zero, right?

Also, I want to ask if any best practices for call setter of autowired bean??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All beans are singleton by default, so yes one way is to reset it.

But imho thats an ugly solution.

What you should do is to define a dedicated `JmsTemplate` `@Bean` that you custom configure and then `autowire` where you need.

If you need another `JmsTemplate` for any other place you define a second `@Bean` and you separate these two by using `@Qualifiers`.

Answer (score 2):

All beans are singleton by default, so I think that you should reset it as you suggest.

As stated in [Spring`s documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html):

> The singleton scope is the default scope in Spring. (...)
>   When a bean is a singleton, only one shared instance of the bean will
>   be managed, and all requests for beans with an id or ids matching that
>   bean definition will result in that one specific bean instance being
>   returned by the Spring container.

This means that the next time `jmsTemplate` is called, it will have its previously added state-data.

There are other bean scopes, which you can view in the source above.

In terms of using field injection via the `@AutoWired` annotation, it is generally not considered a good practice due to various issues listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892204/11812518) (prefer constructor or setter injection instead).