# Mock NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I try to do a Junit test for the method getPersonsFromAddress() in my service, i try to mock the object model, but when i execute the test a NullPointerException appears in the service when model.getPersons() is called.

Here is my service with the method getPersonsFromAddress():

```
@Service
public class ChildAlertService {

    @Autowired
    private Model model;

    @Autowired
    private Util util;

     public List<Person> getPersonsFromAdress (String address) {
         List<Person> listPersons = model.getPersons();
         List<Person> listPersonsFromAddress = new ArrayList<>();
         for (Person person : listPersons) {
             if(person.getAddress().contains(address)) {                    
                 listPersonsFromAddress.add(person);
                }
         }       
            return listPersonsFromAddress;
        }
```

Here is my test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ChildAlertServiceTest {

    private static ChildAlertService childAlertService;

    @Mock
    private Model model;

    @BeforeAll
    private static void setUp() {
        childAlertService = new ChildAlertService();
    }

    @Test
     public void testGetPersonsFromAdress () {
        List<Person> listPersons = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.setFirstName("John");
        person1.setFirstName("Boyd");
        person1.setAddress("1509 Culver St");


        listPersons.add(person1);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setFirstName("Roger");
        person2.setFirstName("Boyd");
        person1.setAddress("1509 Culver St");

        listPersons.add(person2);

        Person person3 = new Person();
        person3.setFirstName("Jonanathan");
        person3.setFirstName("Marrack");
        person3.setAddress("29 15th St");

        listPersons.add(person3);

        when(model.getPersons()).thenReturn(listPersons);

        String address = "1509 Culver St";
        List <Person> listPersonResult = childAlertService.getPersonsFromAdress(address);
        assertNotNull(listPersonResult);
        }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized `model` in `ChildAlertService` in your tests. Your Mock is never used.

In your prod code you rely on field injection.

See: [What exactly is Field Injection and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it)

The cleanest approach is to use constructor injection in your service, and using that constructor in your tests (either manually, or via `@InjectMocks`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring you can use `@SpyBean` or `@MockBean` instead of plain `@Mock`. These come with `spring-boot-starter-test`.

but, I think better solution is to actually intialize service 
by itself:

```
private ChildAlertService childAlertService;

private Model model;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    model = mock(Model.class);
    childAlertService = new ChildAlertService(model);
}
```