# Internal working of field injection in spring and why is it not recommended to use

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

As the title suggests , I want to know how does field injection internally works in spring , I read many articles on this and got to know few things like below but didn't understood the exact reason behind it :

-> It should not be used because when you do unit testing then you are dependent upon the spring
container to instantiate the class in case of field injection.

-> You cannot use "final" keyword in case of field injection , means you cannot make the field immutable.

-> It internally uses reflection

I want to know how exactly does @Autowired works internally , how does it uses reflection , I am trying to understand the exact reason behind all the above mentioned points, what happens behind the scenes when we write the below code :

```
@Component
public class B {

    @Autowired
    private A a1;

}
```

I have read similar questions on stack overflow about this topic , but I couldn't find the exact explanation that I am looking.

Comment: Explaining what goes on in detail would be explaining how the application context lifecycle works. You already have 3 of the things why you shouldn't do it, there is another more pressing one, the fact that it hides the fact that you need (mandatory) dependencies to be using the object. When doing `new YourService()` and it requires 3 repositories, you simply don't know and prevents you actually from writing a unit test (which leads to your first reason, that you need the container technology to determine what to inject).

Comment: Please link to the similar questions you have read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring has a concept of Bean Post Processors.

When spring builds a bean it applies registered bean post processors that help to "initialize" the bean.

So, there is `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` that handles autowiring.

Basically it works with an newly created object. Spring introspects the fields of the beans (by using reflection). The fields that have `@Autowired` is a subject for processing with this bean post processor. It finds the candidate for injection in the application context and actually injects the value.

Now given this information, its understandable why final fields cannot be autowired. Leave alone spring, In pure Java, final fields must be instantiated directly right during the declaration (`final int i = 123`) or in the constructor of the class. But the autowiring happens after constructor, so its impossible to autowire the final fields.

As for the unit testing, the private properties must be somehow configured from the test. But since they're encapsulated (yes, spring kind of breaks encapsulation in this case for its usage), its impossible to write a good test for the class that contains fields injection. That's is a reason to switch to constructor injection.

```
public class FieldInjection {
   @Autowired
   private A a;
}
```

VS.

```
public class ConstructorInjection {

   private final A a;

   // this can be generated by lombok, you don't have to put @Autowired on constructor in the case of single constructor, spring will use it to create a bean
   public ConstructorInjection(A a) {
      this.a = a; 
   }
}
```

Now the test for FieldInjection class is impossible:

```
public class FieldInjectionTest {

   @Test
   void test() {
      FieldInjection underTest = new FieldInjection();
      how do you know that you should instantiate A a.  ???? 
   }
}
```

However in the case of constructor injection its a trivial task:

```
public class ConstructorInjectionTest {

   @Test
   void test() {
     A a = mock(A.class);
     ConstructorInjection underTest = new ConstructorInjection(a); 
     // the dependencies must be supplied in the constructor 
     // otherwise its impossible to create an object under test
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I'm read it.    
Please Mark Bramnik if you have references for this subject add it to answer