# Java Spring Boot: Dependency Injection error: Change 1st parameter of abstract method to Optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use dependency injection in Java Spring Boot. Receiving Error below in controller in this line. `productService.updateProduct(product);`

> Error: Change 1st parameter of abstract method from Product to Optional

How can this be resolved?

```
public class Product {
    @Getter @Setter public @Id @GeneratedValue Long productId;
    @Getter @Setter public String productName;
    @Getter @Setter public String productDescription;
    Product() {}

    Product(String productName, String productDescription) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }
}
```

**Interface:**

```
public interface IProductService {
    public Product updateProduct(Product product);
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class ProductService implements IProductService {
    @Override
    public Product updateProduct(Product product){
        product.productName = "test12345";
        return product;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class ProductController {
    ProductRepository repository;
    @Autowired IProductService productService;

    ProductController(IProductService productService, ProductRepository repository) {
        this.productService = productService;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/products/{id}")
    Product one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        var product = repository.findById(id);
        var finalProduct = productService.updateProduct(product); // error in this line
        return finalProduct;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are doing dependency injection in the controller class.

Comment: hi @Shravan I excluded for the Application   { portion  config code, with getbean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And check whether your Repository class return `Optional<Product>`. because findbyId return type of optional. Then your have to use like below.

```
Optional<Product> product = repository.findById(id);
```

And Better to add  @Autowire @Controller annotation no need constructor.

```
@Controller
class ProductController {
@Autowired
private ProductRepository repository;

@Autowire
private IProductService productService;

}
```

Comment: or I can use this, repository.findById(id).orElse(null); , thanks

Comment: Yes you can use that also.

Comment: by the way, its interesting I didn't even had to set the Application config with getbean , etc  , its like AutoWired did everything https://dzone.com/articles/dependency-injection-in-spring  
ApplicationContext context = 
    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AutomatedAnnotationConfig.class);
Car car = context.getBean(Car.class);   
car.start();

Comment: Autowire make it easy everything. It will injecte object from container whenever it required.

Comment: Field injection like this is [_actively discouraged_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it); the constructor is the better approach. (With Lombok, which it appears OP is using, `@AllArgsConstructor` or `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will generate it.)

Comment: Spring boot main concept of dependency injection we can achieve with any type of injection. While doing the Autowire no need initial the object whenever it needed it will inject from context no need additional work. What are you trying to say and what your concerns.

Comment: And we did not raised any concerns about AllArgsConstructor and RequiredArgsConstructor.