# CommandLineRunner Never Executes (Spring Boot 2.6.7)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to learn Spring Boot and restful application from an online tutorial. But the code I wrote for it somehow gives me an error. I have written a `CommandLineRunner` class like so:

```
package com.trial.cas.preload;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.trial.cas.employee.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import com.trial.cas.employee.pojo.Employee;


@Configuration
class LoadDatabase implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger log = java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("LoadDatabase");
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        log.info("Preloading " + employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Bilbo Baggins", "burglar")));
        log.info("Preloading " + employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Frodo Baggins", "thief")));      
    }
}
```

My `EmployeeRepository` class is like this:

```
package com.trial.cas.preload;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.trial.employee.pojo.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

My main class is written like:

```
package com.trial.cas.logging.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CASLoggingToolApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        SpringApplication.run(CASLoggingToolApplication.class, args);       
    }
}
```

But when I run the Spring Boot application, the lines in the `run` method never execute. I have a debug point point in the first line of the run method. But that never gets triggered.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using the `@Component` annotation instead of `@Configuration`. Also, how does your package structure look like?

Comment: Hello, try changing the `@Configuration` to `@Component` the commanLineRunner needs to be a bean in order to be executed

Comment: @dunni All of the classes I mentioned are in different packages. Would that cause a problem? Let me add the package declarations to the classes. So that it might make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Spring Boot will only scan packages below the package of the main application class (in your example it would be the package `com.trial.cas.logging.example` and all subpackages.

You can either move the application class to a common super package for your application, or specify all other packages, that should be scanned for beans etc. on the annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.trial.cas.logging.example", "com.trial.cas.preload"})
```

Comment: There were a few more changes that I had to do. But at least your answer pointed me to the right direction. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@Component` instead of `@Configuration` when annotating your LoadDatabase class.
Also, if I recall correctly, for Spring Boot to run properly it is necessary to annotate your EmployeeRepository with `@Repository`.

Another last tip, try to avoid field injections like:

```
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
```

It has several drawbacks compared to constructor injection, which are described in detail in this answer: [What exactly is Field Injection and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892204/15512520)

Instead use constructor injection, like this:

```
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Autowired
public LoadDatabase(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository){
 this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
}
```

Comment: I switched to `@Component` and added the `@Repository` to the `EmployeeRepository`. But the result turned out to be the same. Still doesn't execute.  I also did the constructor injection instead of the field.

Comment: The `@Repository` annotation is not necessary on Spring Data interfaces (in fact, it's even wrong to put it there and will produce a warning log message on startup).