# Mock autowired field inside test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm fairly new to Mockito, but can't find an answer to my question anywhere. I have a class I want to test, and need to mock a class that is an autowired field inside that test class. I'm using doReturn to try to get a method to return a certain value for the mocked class, but that method keeps returning null instead of the value. If I use Mockito.mock with SpringRunner, the mock doesn't work at all, and the method itself gets called somehow. I've been rotating between @MockBean, @Mock, and Mockito.mock, but none of them seem to work. Neither class has a constructor, and adding one will break the code.

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) //also tried @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class), but that failed as well
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {...})
public class testProcessorClass() {

    @Autowired Cache cache; //dependency

    @MockBean Comm comm; //Also tried @Mock, with @InjectMocks/initMocks

    @Autowired Processor processor; //test class

    @Before
    public void init() {
        InputObj l = new InputObj();
        ReturnData r = new ReturnData();
        Mockito.doReturn(r).when(comm).checkOut(l, id); id is a hardcoded id string known beforehand, both parameters are passed in correctly
    }

    @Test
    public void testProcessorMethod() {
        Request reqData = new Request(versionId, dataString);
        Response response = processor.processRequest(reqData);
        //response should output a JSON string that contains a key whose value is "SUCCESS", but it either outputs "ERROR" or the whole JSON string outputs {"error: "invalid input"}
    }
    
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Processor {
    @Autowired Cache cache;
    @Autowired Comm comm;

    @Async
    public Response processResponse() {
        //Does a bunch of calculations, too much code to include here
        ReturnData return = comm.checkOut(l, "id"); //This returns null when using @MockBeans/@Mock and returns the key "ERROR" in JSON format when using Mockito.mock, with a random string for a value
        
    }
}
```

Comm class:

```
@Configuration
public class Comm {
    //this class has no constructor, and adding one breaks the code

    public ReturnData checkOut(...) {
        //returns a private method that has a bug in it, which is why I'm mocking the class in the first place
    }
}
```

I just need the checkOut method to return the JSON string I want it to return rather than returning null or some invalid JSON string. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: [Don't use field injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it). Use [constructor injection (`baeldung.com`)](https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring) instead.

Comment: I can't, the Comm class doesn't have a constructor and I can't add one without the code breaking, I didn't write anything but the unit test unfortunately so I can't change much