# Spring drawbacks of Lazy annotation

Tags: spring

I want to resolve a circular dependency with it.

I am aware that there is a drawback of this annotation namely in case of a bean misconfiguration the error will come to the surface only at invocation time:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html

> "Please note that such a lazy-resolution proxy will always be
> injected; if the target dependency does not exist, you will only be
> able to find out through an exception on invocation. As a consequence,
> such an injection point results in unintuitive behavior for optional
> dependencies."

My question is this really a drawback in any sense if I already use the given bean as non-lazy singleton at other parts of application? Which basically proves that the bean itself can be created.

**example:**

```
@Component
class A {
  @Autowired
   private B b;
}

@Component
class B {
  @Autowired
  @Lazy
   private A a;
}

@Component
class C {
  @Autowired
   private A a; <- this is the evidence that the bean can be created so it wont fail when injecting it into classB when invoked
}
```

Comment: If you are dealing with circular dependency problems, then your problem is not really the injection itself. Keep in mind that [field injection is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39892204/10621296)

Comment: The problem is not your annotations or method of injection but the circular dependency. You really should be fixing that and not implement a workaround/hack with `@Lazy`. But that is all IMHO ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your configuration is correct, it should work.  In some cases, you *need* circular dependencies and this is the best way that I've found to implement.

Constructor injection is better but won't always work.

Alternatively, you can inject the `BeanFactory` and fetch in a `@PostConstruct` or `afterPropertiesSet()` method, but using `@Lazy` property injection seems cleaner.