# Null autowired field in some controller functions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-aop

I'm new to Java and Spring. My problem is that using the autowired field in some of my controller functions throws NullPointerException.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {
     
    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listCustomers(Model model) {
        List<Customer> customers = customerService.getCustomers();
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        return "list-customer";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    private String save(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer) {
        customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
        return "redirect:/customer/list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete")
    private String delete(@RequestParam("customerId") int id, Model model) {
        customerService.removeCustomer(customerService.getCustomer(id));
        return "redirect:/customer/list";
    }
}
```

This happens in the `save` or `delete` function but not in the `list`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.hamid.springdemo.service.CustomerService.getCustomer(int)" because "this.customerService" is null

I should mention that I recently added AOP support to my project, but I have no idea whether it is related or not.

Comment: Does class `CustomerService` have a bean-defining annotation (`@Service`, `@Component`, ...)? --- I recommend reading: [What exactly is Field Injection and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890849/what-exactly-is-field-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Comment: Yes, it does. I wonder how is it working in list function :(

`@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
//services
}`
@Turing85

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github project?

Comment: I'm just learning and I'm watching the Udemy course and writing the code simultaneously. I can share zip of my project, is it good?

Comment: I am not willing to download some zip from somewhere. Creating a github account is free and not time-consuming. Learning git should be on your to-dos anyway, and you should be up and running within minutes.