# How to implement LDAP authentication and Database Role mapping in Grails

Tags: java, grails, spring-security-ldap

i'm trying to implement Active Directory authentication and Database role mapping in grails. Quiet alright I've had the app configured with LDAP but once I'm logged in I get redirected with this message "Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page.". How can I achieve user role mapping?

Comment: using ldap template and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515345/best-practice-for-configuring-spring-ldaptemplate-via-annotations-instead-of-xml

Comment: does this also work in grails?